# Ignoring one or more fields during serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, binary

I want to serialize a class that derives from `Exception` with `XmlSerializer` and `BinaryFormatter`. My problem is that I want to ignore some of the fields of the exception class while serializing.

I know that I normally can do this with attributes, but I don't have the source for the exception class and therefore I can't add attributes. Is there any way to tell the serializer not to serialize some of the fields of the exception class?

Please note that I need a solution for both binary and XML serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you are looking for is provided by [XmlAttributes.XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx), at least for XML serialization. I just used it and it worked all right. Here is a piece of code that I use to build a serializer for my `User` class that ignores the `UserName` property:

```
private static XmlSerializer UserSerializer()
{
    XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

    XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
    attrs.XmlIgnore = true;
    xOver.Add(typeof(User), "UserName", attrs);

    return new XmlSerializer(typeof(User), xOver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about serialising a class like :

```
public class ExceptionSerializer {
    private readonly Exception _Ex;

    public serializableException(Exception e) {
      _Ex = e;
    }

    [Flag_you_want_here]
    public SerializableMessage { get{ _Ex.Message;} }

}
```

Could that be an idea ?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but isn't there another opportunity to do this? Something like:
Serializer.AddAttributeRule("Message", XmlAttributeType.Ignore)?
Because I want to use the solution for other Classes too and it would be much easier then encapsulating all fields I want to serialize.